# parametro $_GET en la URL no se obtiene correctamente

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy intentando insertar un registro en una base de datos mediante un formulario con PHP. Estos datos introducidos son enviados mediante "POST" a un documento php para realizar la consulta SQL.
Este documento contiene pues, estas variables, y una llamada a una función **registrarUsuarios()** que se comunica con
la capa de datos para hacer la consulta.

```
//registroUsuario.php

$usuario=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['usuario']));
$password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));
$pais=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['pais']));
$cp=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['cp']));
$ciudad=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['ciudad']));
$direccion=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['direccion']));

$registro=registrarUsuario($usuario,$password,$pais,$cp,$ciudad,$direccion);

/*
Dependiendo de si $registro contiene datos, pasamos por URL el parámeto "?registro=..."
De esta manera, con $_GET en el documento redireccionado, podremos mostrar un mensaje o crear 
contenido
dependiendo de su valor
*/
if (!$registro) {
header('Location:../presentacion/administrador.php?registro=false');
}else {
header('Location:../presentacion/administrador.php?registro=true');
}
```

La consulta que realmente quiero hacer es de un usuario que ya esté registrado a drede, de manera que me arroje un error PDOException. Por ello, la función la he metido en un bloque try-catch, y ahora que ha fallado, quiero redireccionar a la pagina para mostrar el mensaje al usuario.

```
//consultaBD.php

function registrarUsuario($usuario,$password,$pais,$cp,$ciudad,$direccion){

try {
   $contrasenia=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

   $base=conexionBD();
   $sql="INSERT INTO hospitales (Correo, Clave, Pais, CP, Ciudad, Direccion) VALUES 
     (:usuario, :password, :pais, :cp, :ciudad, :direccion)";
   $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

   $resultado->bindParam(':usuario',$usuario);
   $resultado->bindParam(':password',$contrasenia);
   $resultado->bindParam(':pais',$pais);
   $resultado->bindParam(':cp',$cp);
   $resultado->bindParam(':ciudad',$ciudad);
   $resultado->bindParam(':direccion',$direccion);

   $resultado->execute();

if (!$resultado) {
    header('Location:../presentacion/administrador.php?registro=false');

}else {return $resultado;} 

} catch (PDOException $th) {
   echo ('error: '.$th->getMessage(). '<br>');
}

$resultado=null;
$base=null;

}
```

Esto entra en el catch{}, por lo tanto la variable de **$registro** del documento **registroUsuarios.php** no contiene nada y redirige bien al documento anterior:

```
if (!$registro) {
header('Location:../presentacion/administrador.php?registro=false');
}
```

La verdadera duda es, si en la URL tengo **/GestorPedidos/presentacion/administrador.php?registro=false** por que me muestra el mensaje correspodiente a **registro=true** cuando deberia mostrar **Ha habido un problema al registrar**.

```
      <div class="error">
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']==true){
            echo '<h2>Registro con exito</h2>';
        }elseif (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']==false) {
            echo '<h2>Ha habido un problema al registrar</h2>';
        }
        ?>   
       </div>
```

[image: url]

[image: mensaje equivocado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre, siempre, siempre, asegúrate como llegan los datos a tus archivos procesadores.

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";

if (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']=='true'){
    echo '<h2>Registro con exito</h2>';
}elseif (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']=='false') {
    echo '<h2>Ha habido un problema al registrar</h2>';
}
```

Que es lo pasa? el valor de **$_GET['registro']** llega como texto ('true' o 'false'), no como bool, entonces debes hacer la comparación como texto y funciona perfecto.

Si la respuesta soluciona tu duda, no olvides marcarla como **Aceptada**. Graxxx

Comment: Vaya! justamente acabo de responder esto yo mismo al darme cuenta. Muchas gracias, era esto. Te marco como válida

Comment: Gracias @JoseL.

Answer (score 1):

Al asignar directamente el valor "true" o "false" a la url, estos son de tipo String:

```
header('Location:../presentacion/administrador.php?registro=false');
```

Por ello no me reconocía el parámetro en el siguiente código, ya que son booleanos:

```
   <div class="error">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']==true){
        echo '<h2>Registro con exito</h2>';
    }elseif (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']==false) {
        echo '<h2>Ha habido un problema al registrar</h2>';
    }
    ?>   
   </div>
```

La solución la he conseguido entrecomillando "true" y "false" al ser String y no Boolean.

```
    if (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']=="true"){
        echo '<h2>Registro con exito</h2>';
    }elseif (isset($_GET['registro']) && $_GET['registro']=="false") {
        echo '<h2>Ha habido un problema al registrar</h2>';
    }
```

La otra forma es asignar una variable booleana a la url en vez de directamente el String:

```
$registrado=false;
header("Location:../presentacion/administrador.php?registro=$registrado");
```

De esta última forma, si es un parámetro booleano.